# How to reuse class in Puppet

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrant-provision

I have this puppet class

```
class project::className(
  $program_name = '',
  $command = ''
) {
   ....
}
```

And I'm using it like this

```
class { 'project::classname':
  program_name => 'programe_name',
  command => 'ls /dev/'
}
```

This works fine, but when I used it twice like this

```
class { 'project::classname':
  program_name => 'programe_name',
  command => 'ls /dev/'
}

class { 'project::classname':
  program_name => 'programe_name2',
  command => 'ls /dev/'
}
```

Vagrant Provision is giving me this error

> Error: Duplicate declaration: Class[project::classname] is already declared in file ..

How can I reuse the class?

Comment: You need understand the difference of `class` and `defined` type.

Comment: @BMW oh ok, so what I'm trying to do is not possible with `class`?

Comment: no, do with defined type.

Comment: @BMW ok, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need understand the difference of class and defined types.

> Classes Vs Defined Types
>
> Classes are not to be thought of in the ‘object oriented’ meaning of a
> class. This means a machine belongs to a particular class of machine.
>
> For instance, a generic webserver would be a class. You would include
> that class as part of any node that needed to be built as a generic
> webserver. That class would drop in whatever packages, etc, it needed
> to do.
>
> Defined types on the other hand (created with ‘define’) can have many
> instances on a machine, and can encapsulate classes and other
> resources. They can be created using user supplied variables. For
> instance, to manage iptables, a defined type may wrap each rule in the
> iptables file, and the iptables configuration could be built out of
> fragments generated by those defined types.
>
> Usage of classes and defined types, in addition to the built-in
> managed types, is very helpful towards having a managable Puppet
> infrastructure.

Refer: https://web.archive.org/web/20160305195130/https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/best_practices.html